# DroidX data encryption - which algorithm and how strong?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, security, motorola-droid-x, encryption

I have a follow-up to the question posted [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/which-disk-encryption-standard-is-used-in-honeycomb). I recently got a 2.3 DroidX phone, and noticed that it as well has data encryption option. I pulled an SD card from device, and noticed that folder structure is intact. I tried reading file from the SD card, which was produced by a photo application, and it was unreadable, however the file itself contained some data which was [not random](http://vvcap.net/db/W7cHJIYjVPFPdS7pzN40.htp), which to me indicated that not the whole file was AES'ed. I was also able to put an unencrypted file on SD card which was readable afterwards.

So, the question is: does anyone know what encryption methodology is being used here, what algorithms are in place, and how strong they are against experienced attacker?

**EDIT**: My friend got a droid2, which also runs gingerbread 2.3.3, and it has data encryption feature too. So... is data encryption an android feature or specific to Motorola devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, DroidX uses [ecryptfs](http://ecryptfs.sourceforge.net)

Following are mount options on /data/data:

```
rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,ecryptfs_sig=****************,
    ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough
```

I would imagine this means that encryption key here is 32 bytes, which is 256 bits, which seems pretty good to me.

Comment: Good find!  Any pointers to the Motorola DroidX source code that shows the ecryptfs bits, specifically?  I'm an eCryptfs upstream developer looking for it.

Comment: As a followup to my last comment, I broke it out to its own question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20105/motorola-droidx-ecryptfs-related-sources