# Motorola DroidX eCryptfs related Sources?

Tags: encryption, open-source

I see over in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13174/droidx-data-encryption-which-algorithm-and-how-strong) that the Motorola DroidX uses [eCryptfs](http://launchpad.net/ecryptfs) to do its data encryption.

I'm trying to find the source code of the mount.ecryptfs that version of Android uses (as I am one of the authors and maintainers of the eCryptfs upstream project).

I found [this site](http://sourceforge.net/motorola/droidx/home/Home/), but I'm unable to find any of the (GPLv2) ecryptfs related sources.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the [Motorola source for the droidx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/droidx.motorola/). I think this is just the kernel source, but I haven't looked through it. If this isn't what you are looking for, then I would try and get in touch with someone that is part of [MOTODEV](http://developer.motorola.com/).

Comment: Hmm, well, I've scoured those.  I've seen multiple references to the DroidX *using* ecryptfs, but I've yet to find their sources for ecryptfs.

Comment: Doing some research in to your question I discovered the same thing. Everyone says it uses it, but I couldn't find the sources. I would try to contact motorola directly about it and see if you get a response.